# Localization with Facebook Share for website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, localization

I have a website that supports few languages. Page detects and displays respective language based on browser settings (user can select desired language too).

Now id like to share this website with Facebook share. 
According to Fb documentation i need to set a number of meta fields for needed language.

How can i detect a language Facebook is trying to scrape my website for? I was trying to use query`s fb_locale parameter, but it does not seem to pass this one with needed language.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to Fb documentation i need to set a number of meta fields for needed language.

This was never available for normal posts/shares in the first place, only for Open Graph stories - and for those it has been removed with API version 2.8, too.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_8_deprecations

There is no way any more to do what you want.

Comment: Mean no localization for share on FB anymore? Right? One more thing, what they mean by OG Story? A set of og: meta tags?

Comment: Open Graph stories: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph